# Evaluate polinom with matrices

Tags: matrix

Let's say that I have the following polynom f = a+b+ab

I want to evaluate this expression like this:

`f/.{a->{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, b->{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}}`

How can I do this given the fact that the dot (.) is the matrix multiplication operator in Mathematica.

Comment: I do not see what the problem is. Could you give us a specific example and tell us what you expect as the result and what result you are getting instead ?

Comment: I think you either want `f = a + b + a.b` or `f = a + b + a b` (notice the space between `a` and `b` for element-wise multiplication).

Comment: There isno problem, apart from a missing `.` in your expression for `f`. Or a missing `*` for element-wise multiplication. @Edmund beat me to it by a few secs :)

Comment: See here an example: https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/1616c13c-3707-4b70-b912-5182bd8538bd.

Comment: The problem is that is I cannot change the polynom expression and use the dot sign .
I generate some random polynoms - using linear combination of SymmetricPolynomial - and then I want to evaluate these polynoms using matrices as values. This is the problem.

Comment: Try `f /. ab -> a.b` or `f /. ab -> a b` depending on the result you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Edmund. It works.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to change the products to matrix products. Taking your example

```
f = a + b^2;
m = n = {{1, 2}, {1, 2}};

f1 = f /. {Times[a__, b__] :> Dot[a, b], Power[a__, n_] :> MatrixPower[a, n]};

f /. {a -> m, b -> n}
f1 /. {a -> m, b -> n}
```

> {{2, 6}, {2, 6}}
>
> {{4, 8}, {4, 8}}

And you get the right answer. For your example you don't need to replace `Times`. I keep it to make it more general.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much.